# How to include Cucumber step definitions from a gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cucumber

I'm working on a gem that includes some common classes for a few different projects. The projects use Cucumber with existing step definitions.

However, I've discovered that some of the step definitions are general (used across all the projects) so I'd like to extract those from the projects and just put them in the gem.

The problem is, even by defining the gem's `spec.files` and `spec.require_paths` to point to the step definitions, it still doesn't pick up the step definitions in the gem.

I suspect that in the gem I need to configure Cucumber to "know" about the step definitions in that gem, so that when I load the gem via one of the projects, Cucumber will already have those step definitions in it's load path... but I don't know how to do that?

I welcome any suggestions!

BTW, this question is *close* to what I'm asking: [How can a gem provide Cucumber features and step definitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11675137/how-can-a-gem-provide-cucumber-features-and-step-definitions)

However, the goal is to not have to do an explicit `require` within the project that is using the gem. Ideally, just including the gem in the Gemfile will be sufficient to have Cucumber "know" about the step definitions from the gem. I just need to know what to configure in the gem to make that happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide step definitions in a gem simply by putting them in a file and instructing the user to require that file in their env.rb.

Comment: Vignesh, thanks for the answer but in my last paragraph I was specifically asking about a way that does not involve doing a `require`.